# Soundcloud api followings gets a 503 but not favourites

Tags: soundcloud

I feel like this maybe an issue with the SoundCloud API itself so apologies if it doesn't belong here. I have the following calls in my application. Up until a few weeks ago they where both functioning. Now the "favorites" call functions and "followings" call returns a 503.

I am a bit stuck on how to proceed.

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{user}/followings.json?client_id={key}

http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{user}/favorites.json?client_id={key}
```

The documentation states my calls are still valid.

```
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users
```

Is there anything wrong with the request structure. I have tested it straight up in a web browser outside of my app with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared to be that the api has changed to require a user id not a username hit this api endpoint to get the id

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{username}?client_id={someid}
```

Then use the id in the url instead and it works :D